# Add a Jalali month to a Jalali Date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, calendar, persian

I have a date in Jalali (Persian system of Date) which I need to be forwarded 1 month. The problem is that when I add 1 month using `myDateTime.AddMonths(1)` my date forwards by 1 Gregorian month, whereas I want a Jalali month.

For example if my Date (Format: yyyy-MM-dd) is **2013-02-28** Gregorian and **1391/12/10** Jalali, and I add one month it will be **2013-03-28** Gregorian (that is alright) and **1392/01/08** (that is wrong and should be *1392/01/10* ).

Having said all the story above, is there a way I can Add one month to a date based on my culture or region or something?

Comment: Unfortunately there is a weak support for Jalali calendar, specially GUI components in MS products.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `System.Globalization.PersianCalendar` instance methods (which pretty much behave like static methods), as in:

```
var persianCalendar = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
var today = DateTime.Today;
var nextMonth = persianCalendar.AddMonths(today, 1);
```